# pd.read_excel is combining the first columns into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a simple code to import an Excel file. However, the command is combining the first two rows into one. I would like to keep it separated (as it is in the Excel file).

```
db=pd.read_excel('fileaddress', sheetname='Sheet1')
```

Comment: the separator is likely not being interpreted.

Comment: Hey! Can you post a small example? Maybe a screen shot?